# how to generate random integer array and provide to another file for performing operation on the array

Tags: c++, arrays

so i want to run the program only once from the arrayoperation.cpp file which will execute also the generate.cpp and each time a new set of N numbers will be generated.
when i run the program separately it worked not working for this automation. so i will not run two codes separately one after another.

**Generate.cpp**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

class Generate
{
// Define the number of runs for the test data 
// generated 
#define RUN 10

// Define the range of the test data generated 
#define MAX 1000

public:
int generate(int x) 
{ 

    // Uncomment the below line to store 
    // the test data in a file 
     freopen("Test_Cases.in", "w", stdout); 

    // For random values every time 
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", rand() % MAX); 

    // Uncomment the below line to store 
    // the test data in a file 
    fclose(stdout); 
    return 0; 
} 
};
```

**ArrayOperation.cpp**

```
// Example program
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <S:\Generate.cpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
//  cin>>T;

//while(T--)
//{
    int N;
    cin>>N;

    Generate obj1;
    obj1.generate(N);

    int A[N];
string inFileName = "Test_Cases.in";
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            inFile >> A[i];
            cout << A[i] << " ";
        }

        inFile.close(); // CLose input file
    }

for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}

int max1=-999;
int min1=999;
int i=0;

for(i=0;i<N-1;i++)
{
if(abs(A[i+1]-A[i]) >= max1)
    max1 = abs(A[i+1] - A[i]);

if(abs(A[i]-A[i+1]) <= min1)
    min1 = abs(A[i] - A[i+1]);
}
cout<<endl;
cout<< max1<< " "<<min1;

cout<<endl;
cout<<max1-min1;
}
```

so i want to run the program only once from the array operation file which will execute also the generate and each time a new set of N numbers will be generated.
when i run the program separately it worked not working for this calling the first programme method.

Comment: @user4581301 i copied few stuffs from geeksforgeeks i never use any other header if i write bits/std once.

Comment: `freopen("Test_Cases.in", "w", stdout);` doesn't look quite right. This should write the program's output into the input file.

Comment: Looking things over, `freopen("Test_Cases.in", "w", stdout);` is definitely a problem. It repoints stdout at a file which is is closed shortly after. This means that all of the future attempts to output the program results fail.

Comment: `#include <S:\Generate.cpp>` is generally not a good idea. You can include anything, but cpp file are typically full of definitions that will result in linker errors if duplicated. This cpp file is an exception and probably should be a it should be a .h header file.

Comment: @user4581301 if I change the int generate() to int main. And run the program   it writes the output to file. Then i can open it again in array_operation.cpp and can get the output very correctly.

Comment: @user4581301 did u paste this code to two different files and run them separately.

Comment: Separating into two files doesn't do a bit of good. `#include <S:\Generate.cpp>` copies Generate.cpp into ArrayOperation.cpp and then compiles the combined file.

Comment: What I expect from this program is for `generate` to successfully write the input file and `main` to be able to read this file, perform operations, but be unable to write any subsequent output because it no longer has an open output file.

Comment: @user4581301 so could you run it finally? could you find the error. pls paste the working code in answer

Comment: I m using bloodshed dev c++ on windows. if that helps in anyway.

Comment: Ran it yesterday. Saw exactly what I expected. explained the problem a few posts above. You have yet to state what the problem you are having is.

Comment: @user4581301 the code doesnt run. shows error paste the code in devc++ and if you can fix the code pls do. then write the answer here.

Comment: I'm not writing an answer until I know which of the problems in your code you want fixed. You need to be more specific than It doesn't run.  Give[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a teread for suggestions. But the first thing you should do is rewrite `generate` so that it doesn't break `stdout`. Open the file in a `std::ofstream` rather than hijacking `stdout`. Write the numbers into the stream with the `<<` operator. You don't even have to close the stream when you're done. `fstream` automatically cleans up when it goes out of scope.